# Duplicate opportunity product search

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

Whenever you add a product to an opportunity there is a search box that is much more robust than the common lookup value search box. You can filter products by all sorts of values. I'm creating an object very similar to an Opportunity Product Object, but any lookup value I create seems to be a regular lookup. Is there a way I can duplicate this search function on a custom object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can implement a custom lookup menu with visualforce and apex. it may takes some time but it's feasible.

Comment: Can you add some detail to this?